# How to find IP addresses in OpsWorks

Tags: ip, chef-infra, chef-recipe, aws-opsworks, devops

I am not good with Ohai. I would like to know if there is any way to find out all ip address (including own) of nodes from respective subnet through Chef recipe.

I have created one layer in AWS Opswork and want to add each node's ip addr and hostname in the configuration file. Any help will highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So this depends a little bit on if you want to get all the instances in a *layer*, or all the total instances in your stack.

For the first, something like this - untested! - code for your recipe *should* work:

```
my_layer_name = "my_database_layer_or_whatever" 

node[:opsworks][:layers][my_layer_name][:instances].each do |current_instance, current_instance_data| 

    puts node[:opsworks][:layers][my_layer_name][:instances][current_instance][:private_dns_name]
end
```

Note that this will get you the private dns name - so internal to the OpsWorks network. You may or may not want that - there are a dozen or so other attributes on the object, including the public IP address.

If you wanted to get instances for the entire stack, I'm betting you could loop through `node[:opsworks][:layers]`, as I've looped through the instances here. Just another loop.

Also note this code is for Chef 11. In [Chef 12 things have changed a bit](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/application-management/post/Tx1T5HNA1TSU8NH/AWS-OpsWorks-Now-Supports-Chef-12-for-Linux).

If you're using Chef 12, I found the documentation on how to [use/search the Chef Data Bags for OpsWorks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/data-bag-json-instance.html).

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your valuable help and time. I will try it now, hope it will work!!